# which one should I use, grunt-ngdoc or grunt-ngdocs to generate the api and tutorial doc for my angularjs app?

Tags: gruntjs

There are 2 grunt plugins for generating docs for Angularjs applications.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ngdoc

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ngdocs

What's the difference and which one should I use?

grunt-ngdoc

```
    ngdoc: {
      options: {
        dest: 'docs'
        scripts: ['../app.min.js'],
        html5Mode: true,
        startPage: '/api',
        title: 'My Documentation',
        analytics: {
              account: 'UA-08150815-0',
              domainName: 'my-domain.com'
        },
        discussions: {
              shortName: 'my',
              url: 'http://my-domain.com',
              dev: false
        }
      },
      tutorial: {
        src: ['content/tutorial/*.ngdoc'],
        title: 'Tutorial'
      },
      api: {
        src: ['src/**/*.js', '!src/**/*.spec.js'],
        title: 'API Documentation'
      }
    }
```

ngdocs

```
    ngdocs: {
      options: {
        dest: 'docs'
        scripts: ['../app.min.js'],
        html5Mode: true,
        startPage: '/api',
        title: "My Awesome Docs",
        image: "path/to/my/image.png",
        imageLink: "http://my-domain.com",
        titleLink: "/api",
        bestMatch: true,
        analytics: {
              account: 'UA-08150815-0',
              domainName: 'my-domain.com'
        },
        discussions: {
              shortName: 'my',
              url: 'http://my-domain.com',
              dev: false
        }
      },
      tutorial: {
        src: ['content/tutorial/*.ngdoc'],
        title: 'Tutorial'
      },
      api: {
        src: ['src/**/*.js', '!src/**/*.spec.js'],
        title: 'API Documentation'
      }
    }
```

Comment: There are 4-5 npm modules for angular documentation generation, you should update your post ;-). Or be more specific with question and write you are searching for a grunt-plugin which generates angular documentation, then there are at least 3 plugins.

Comment: Go with ng-docs. It is the official one.

Answer (score 14):

I wondered the same thing today.  I noticed ngdocs https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs was undergoing more active development than ngdoc https://github.com/bevacqua/grunt-ngdoc.  As a result I decided to go with ngdocs.

UPDATE: I tried both and was able to get ngdocs working for my project, but was not able to get ngdoc working.

Comment: +1 I had the same experience with `grunt-ngdoc`. I think that project might be broken. `grunt-ngdocs` works and looks balla, though.

Comment: Same for me, ngdoc always "generated 0 pages".

Comment: this packages to old for ng1.6 and ng2

Answer (score 1):

There is also [grunt-docular](http://grunt-docular.com/) to generate documentation in [AngularJS' style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api). But with no activity for months :( To me it looks angular team did some improvements since then, but only for their internal use

Comment: I'm coming to this party late, but I'm not quite ready to give up on grunt-docular. It makes it easy to have the angular documentation along side your project's docs, very nice to have when commuting.

Comment: For what it's worth, my company has stepped in and we're now sponsoring the docular project. The site should be back up within the next few days and there will be a corporate maintainer with a bunch of people eager to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the AngularJS wiki does have some information about how to write documentation:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation

> The flavour of `jsdoc` used by AngularJS is called `ngdo`c and is parsed by a Node.js utility called `Dgeni`.

More info about `Dgeni` here: https://github.com/angular/dgeni

Comment: Yes, true. But this has very poor documentation in terms of its usage.

Comment: I have the same experience.

Answer (score 0):

package grunt-ngdocs https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs   works fine (but long time haven't updated)

for ng1.6 works for me:

```
ngdocs: {
  all: ['app/**/*.js']
}
```

you will see the old version of angular 1.2.* in

```
cat docs/js/angular.min.js  | grep v1
 AngularJS v1.2.16
```

but it does not affect your source files.

dont forget run server

e.g using python

```
pushd ./dist; python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9000; popd #v 2.*
pushd ./dist; python -m http.server 9000; popd #v 3.*
```